# How do I define a dynamic template mapping for a field in Elasticsearch while keeping the strict dynamic setting for other fields?

Tags: templates, dynamic, elasticsearch, mapping

I want to create a dynamic mapping for a field in Elasticsearch, but am having trouble doing that while at the same time restricting the creation of other fields by using the "strict" dynamic setting.

As an example, I would like to be able to index docs like the following, where the key of the object in the "members" field is dynamic:

```
POST /groups/group
{
    "members" : {
        "Bob" : {
            "age" : 50
        }
    }
}

POST /groups/group
{
    "members" : {
        "Alice" : {
            "age" : 40
        }
    }
}
```

But I also want to restrict the fields added to the "members" field to the type "object", and restrict the fields within the inner object so that only the "age" field is allowed. So for example, the following two docs should generate an error when I try to index them:

```
POST /groups/group
{
    "members" : {
        "foo" : "bar",
        "Alice" : {
            "age" : 40
        }
    }
}

POST /groups/group
{
    "members" : {
        "Alice" : {
            "foo" : "bar",
            "age" : 40
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the dynamic mapping that I have been experimenting with. This gives me the following error when I try to index one of the docs with the desired structure: "StrictDynamicMappingException[mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [Bob] within [members] is not allowed]".

```
PUT /groups/group/_mapping
{
    "dynamic" : "strict",
    "dynamic_templates" : [
        {
            "members_template" : {
                "path_match" : "members.*",
                "match_mapping_type" : "object",
                "mapping" : {
                    "type" : "object",
                    "properties" : {
                        "{name}" : {
                            "properties" : {
                                "age" : {"type" : "long"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "properties":{
        "members":{
            "type":"object"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried setting "dynamic" to "true" in various parts of the mapping, but that breaks the restrictions that I want to enforce.

Any ideas on how I can allow for dynamic key names in the "members" field while keeping the "strict" setting elsewhere?

Comment: When you're trying this hard to bend a tool out of shape to meet your design, you should reconsider your design. Vastly simpler would be to have a members object with a name field and an age field.

Comment: The contrived examples I used above were just to illustrate the principle of what I'd like to achieve, and I agree that in the example situation the alternative that you suggested would be a much cleaner design.

For the use-case that I'm working on it would be extremely useful to be able to address properties by their path like "members.Bob.age" or "members.Alice.age". I'm accessing these values in a custom scoring script, and addressing them like this saves me iterating over large lists of objects, checking the "name" field of each.

But I also prefer to define mappings where possible :)